# Correct haml syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following html code

```
<input type="radio" name="production23" id="account-production-yes23">
<label for="account-production-yes23">Yes</label>
```

and its corresponding haml syntax from html2haml convertor gives me

```
%input#account-production-yes23{name: "production23", type: "radio"}/ 
%label{for: "account-production-yes23"} Yes
```

It works but i would like to know what / means in the line

```
%input#account-production-yes23{name: "production23", type: "radio"}/
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Haml.info](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html):

> The forward slash character, when placed at the end of a tag definition, causes Haml to treat it as being an empty (or void) element. Depending on the format, the tag will be rendered either without a closing tag (:html4 or :html5), or as a self-closing tag (:xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

> The forward slash character, when placed at the end of a tag definition, causes Haml to treat it as being an empty (or void) element. Depending on the format, the tag will be rendered either without a closing tag (:html4 or :html5), or as a self-closing tag (:xhtml).

Check here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#empty_void_tags_